# How to use classifier for external purposes?

Tags: android, python, machine-learning

I have build a text classifier using sckit-learn. I have to use it in a app that is android based, but main problem is how do I use that in app. One thing I know that I can host a server and get data by requests but it will slow down the working of it, please suggest me some better ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible workflow:

1. Export the Scikit-Learn model in PMML data format using the [JPMML-SkLearn](http://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-sklearn) library.
2. Put the PMML file into App's resources directory (model is relatively stable over time) and/or fetch it from some PMML file download service (model changes often).
3. Evaluate the PMML model in Android App using the [JPMML-Android](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-android) library.